# Fusiontables base map missing when embedded on my blog

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've embedded the HTML code generated from fusiontableslayer wizard into my Google blog and
found that I got only point features with the base map layer all disappeard.
When I zoom in and out, the layer briefly appears but then again goes away.

the link:

http://hkhahm61.blogspot.kr/2014/08/blog-post_21.html

I am a complete novice on javascript, so have no idea as to how to fix the problem.

Is there anay way I can fix this?
Thank you in advance.

The fusiontables HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:500px; height:400px; }
    .layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer_0;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.53506109154479, 128.38037449395748),
        zoom: 7
      });
      var style = [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { saturation: -99 }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.arterial',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.local',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.country',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.province',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.locality',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        }
       ];
      var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
        map: map,
        name: 'Styled Map'
      });
      map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId('map-style');
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col3",
          from: "1aj360PsGiV0GOlmFI0-BaYUnTb2UWiNRC4KmBpyP"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to post at once. Can you reduce it to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this CSS:

```
.post-body img, .post-body .tr-caption-container, .Profile img, .Image img,
.BlogList .item-thumbnail img {
padding: 2px;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

...which affects also the the images used for the map(especially the background-color)

Add this CSS to override it:

```
#map-canvas img{
 padding: 0;
background: transparent;
border: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```